# Function within a Function in Python 3

Tags: python, function, python-3.x, closures

Below is my code:

```
 def before_Upd(self):
     count = 0
     def Update(self):
         if count = 0:
             a = something
             b = something
         count = count+1

         x= min(a,newa)
         self.after(2000,self.Update)
```

I am trying to call a function within another function. I Only want the initial values to be set to something. And from the next iteration onwards to compare the previous minimum value (i.e x) with a new value to get a new minimum(x again).. This has to be done every 2 seconds. The problem here is, Update() is never called. I know this would be something silly but I am not able to figure it out.. TIA for all the suggestions!

Comment: `self.after()` is indented to be part of the `Update()` function.

Comment: If the `self.after()` call is *meant* to be part of the `Update()` function, then there is indeed nothing here to call the `Update()` function in the first place. You either need to call it explicitly at least once.

Comment: @MartijnPieters : I tried doing what you said, calling explicitly Update() but it throws an error saying :"Classname_Task" has no attribute Update(). How do I go about it?

Comment: Ah, remove `self.`; `Update` is not a method.

Answer (score 1):

I can see three problems:

- `self.after()` might well call the nested function, but it itself  part of `Update()`, so it'll never get called. Either unindent it (so it is now part of the parent function and called just once), or call `Update()` explicitly in `before_Upd()` at least once.
- `Update()` is not a method; it doesn't exist on `self`. Remove the `self.` part from the call:

  ```
  self.after(2000, Update)
  ```
- `count` is not a closure variable; it is a *local* variable, because you assign to it.

  Mark it as nonlocal:

  ```
   def before_Upd(self):
       count = 0
       def Update(self):
           nonlocal count
           if count = 0:
               a = something
               b = something
           count = count+1

           x= min(a,newa)

       self.after(2000, Update)
  ```

Comment: One more problem: `self.Update` won’t exist on the object since `Update` is just local to the current execution of `before_Upd`.

Answer (score 0):

Indentation in Python is important. Consider the sample below and how the internal function `test_in` is being invoked by the external function `test_out`:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3 -B

def test_out(arg1):
    cnt = 0
    def test_in(arg2):
        nonlocal cnt
        print('arg2 is {}'.format(arg2))
        if cnt == 0:
            print('cnt is 0')
        cnt += 1

    # indentation here is part of test_out body calling test_in
    test_in(arg1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    for i in range(3):
        test_out(i)
```

In your case, you need to fix the indentation of the `self.after` call.

Also note that you might run into an `UnboundLocalError` with your `count` variable. You may need to mark it with the `nonlocal` keyword or move it to have a greater scope and reference it as a `global`.

Another issue is the `self.after(2000,self.Update)` line. It should be `self.after(2000, Update)` because `Update` is not bound to `self`.

Comment: No reason to make a non-global variable suddenly global. Python 3 has `nonlocal` for that.

Comment: @poke: Yes, I think you caught me with your comment while I was editing it.